# How could I get this to work? (Roblox Lua)

Tags: lua, roblox

So, recently I have become interested in creating a worthy and fun Roblox game. I decided to add a cool feature, where if you go into your assigned room, it will kill your player. Sadly, the code I have currently doesn't seem to work.
Example:

```
local Display = script.parent.Frame.TextLabel.Numberdisplay

number.Value = math.random(101, 113)

Door = "Door"

local numby = Door.. number.Value
Display.Text = number.Value
local player = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer

local Shop = workspace.numby

Shop.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    if hit.Parent == player.Character then
        player.Character.Humanoid:TakeDamage(1000)
    end
end)
```

Any form of help would be great. :)

Comment: Can you please define "doesn't seem to work". Does it crash? Does it call the Touched callback?

Comment: So, I put an invisible block in the assigned room, so if they touch it, meaning they went into their assigned room, it will kill their player. Over all the code just doesn't run.(Nothing happens when you touch the block)

Comment: And just to make sure, is `local Shop = workspace.numby` correct? Did you mean `local Shop = workspace[numby]`?

Comment: You make a `local numby = Door.. number.Value` but never use it you use `local Shop = workspace.numby` was that intended? you may want to take a step back build up a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) this might help you to answer your own question

Comment: Yes, I wanted to access one of the series of invisible blocks(because there are multiple rooms), so I tried to add the word door and the assigned number together, making the name of one of the invisible blocks. But the way I tried to code it, seems like its trying to access an object called numby inside the workspace, not finding the assigned room.

Comment: I am not sure how I would make it look for the door + assigned number in the workspace. not an object called numby inside the workspace.

Comment: I told you the answer :) Take a look at https://www.lua.org/pil/2.5.html

Comment: Also make sure you receive error messages, it should have crashed and told you where the problem is located.

Comment: Thankyou @Luke100000 for your help, it seems your code does indeed work, I just added spaces in the invisible blocks name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know where you got player from but if that's the issue try this:

```
Shop.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
if hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
    hit.Parent.Humanoid.Health = hit.Parent.Humanoid.Health - 9999
end
```

end)

could you also explain what numby is?

Comment: Yes, Numby is the word door added to the assigned room number. If you go to the assigned room which is called or hit the invisible block, it will kill your player. ( the rooms are named Room1, Room2, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

After mixing together @actravaz 's and @Luke100000 's code the door thing worked. Thankyou guys for all your help. :) Answer code:

```
local number = script.Parent.Value
local Display = script.parent.Frame.TextLabel.Numberdisplay
number.Value = math.random(101, 113)
Door = "Door"
local numby = Door.. number.Value
Display.Text = number.Value
local player = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer

local Shop = workspace[numby]

Shop.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    if hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
        hit.Parent.Humanoid.Health = hit.Parent.Humanoid.Health - 9999
    end
end)
```